# Date format for year/month/date'T'/hour/minute/second/timezone in Python

Tags: python, datetime

In Python I would like to turn my str to time object and I am receiving an error.

```
ValueError: time data '2022-04-13T09:52:49-04:00' does not match format
```

What format should I use here?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
>>> datetime.strptime('2022-04-13T09:52:49-04:00',"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 13, 9, 52, 49, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(days=-1, seconds=72000)))
```

Answer (score 0):

[ISO 8601](https://www.iso.org/iso-8601-date-and-time-format.html) format was used, so it is task for [`datetime.datetime.fromisoformat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat)

```
import datetime
d = '2022-04-13T09:52:49-04:00'
dt = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(d)
print(repr(dt))
```

output

```
datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 13, 9, 52, 49, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(days=-1, seconds=72000)))
```